# Form only submitting some rows to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form, populated by an uploaded CSV, and upon submit it saves to my database staging/temp table. However, it's only saving the first 4 of  7 rows.

The form:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$maxPreviewRows = PHP_INT_MAX;  // this will be ~2 billion on 32-bit system, or ~9 quintillion on 64-bit system
$hasHeaderRow = true;
    echo "<form method='post' action='/form-submit' >";
    echo '<table>';

    /*WE WILL NEED TO QA CONDITIONS AND HIGHLIGHT IN RED HERE. ALSO NEED BORDER STYLINGS*/


    if ($hasHeaderRow) {
        $headerRow = fgetcsv($handle);
        echo '<thead><tr>';
        foreach($headerRow as $value) {
            echo "<th>$value</th>";
        }
        echo '</tr></thead>';
    }

    echo '<tbody>';

    $rowCount = 0;
    while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $colCount = 0;
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($row as $value) {
            echo "<td><input name='row[".$rowCount."][".$colCount."]' type='text' value='$value' /></td>";

                $colCount++;
                } 
        echo '</tr>';

        if (++$rowCount > $maxPreviewRows) {
            break;
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
    echo "<input type='submit' name='confirm' value='confirm'>";


            echo '</form>';
            }
```

The submission:

```
foreach ($_POST['row'] as $rowValue)
{
if( is_array($rowValue) && count($rowValue) > 0 )
{
    $sqlFull = "INSERT INTO staging VALUES( DEFAULT, ". substr( str_repeat ( '?, ', count($rowValue) ), 0, -2 ) .")";
    if( !$stmt = $connect->prepare($sqlFull) )
    {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $connect->errno . ") " . $connect->error;
    }
    $stmt->bind_param( str_repeat ( 's', count($rowValue) ), ...$rowValue );

    $stmt->execute();
}
}
```

So it's definitely working but for some reason it's stopping on the fourth row every time. I edit the first field of each row each time and when I check my file dashboard I'll see only the first 4 from each submission.

ANy ideas why this is ending on the 4th row?

UPDATE:

[image: Screenshot of html output for form]

Comment: To troubleshoot, you may want to try outputting the posted data. Someting like `echo"<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";exit;`

Comment: Is probably an encoding thing. Do you have any special characters on the fourth line? Remember it is always good to stick to one encoding, for ex. UTF-8. You can alter the documents encoding in Notepad++ or Sublime Text.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle Possibly, I think I had to alter my original upload code because something was double quoted in one of the records. The guy that creates the CSV files isn't very detail oriented but this is just a secondary way to house these files so it's not very important. Is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: @showdev I put that in and it prints the row array but it looks like it only has array 0-4, so only 5 of 7 rows

Comment: @showdev I'm looking through the CSV and can't find anything in the 5th or 6th row that would cause it to not be inserted

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the rendered HTML (not the PHP, but what it outputs to the browser)?

Comment: You mean for the full 7 row form or the array dump when the form is submitted? It's long code because each row has 229 elements

Comment: The form. I'm just wondering how the inputs end up getting named.

Comment: Ok, just inserted a screenshot that should give an idea, from the inspector

Comment: @showdev does that give you an idea/

Comment: Try to avoid using `INSERT` without specifying columns. This avoids having to call `DEFAULT` on certain values.

Comment: @tadman yeah, I actually had never used DEFAULT but it was a suggestion to fix an issue temporarily and make sure it was inserting without calling all 229 columns right away. And it's working now with DEFAULT, I just have to figure out why it's only getting the first 4 rows

Comment: The other thing you'll want to do is try and normalize this thing because 299 columns is not a sustainable schema. One thing to note is that PDO has much better handling of binding than `mysqli`, it accepts an array, even an associative array, which makes producing those dynamically significantly easier.

Comment: @tadman I'm hoping to definitely do a lot of that in the future. I'm very new to PHP, and I built the database and website for these people, with a file upload that just inserted the CSV straight away. It goes to staging and then splits to smaller tables. But they wanted to see an option for being able to see it in an editable table/form upon upload and save it with edits, so I'm trying to do something that at least works and then refine it form there

Comment: If you want to preserve the raw imports, that's the way to do it, but try and use that as a source for properly normalized records. One thing that helps is to have some kind of import identifier in your table, that is you track each CSV import with time, filename, IP, name of user if applicable, and then each row added to this big table have that identifier in them. When you break out individual records, back-reference the import line that generated them. This helps you track down import mistakes, and if you can show it's simply garbage data they gave you, side-step blame, too.

Comment: @tadman awesome, thank you! I'll definitely keep that in mind. For the time being, do you seen anything in the current code that would possibly cause the issue of importing 4 of 7 rows?

Comment: Try using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` approach, you can pull in CSVs directly into MySQL. That'll help validate if it's a structural problem in the CSV itself, a MySQL problem, or a PHP problem.

Comment: Ok, I tried something. I duplicated the known good 4 rows and when I did that it inserted all 8, so maybe a data issue in the CSV. Is there a way I can override/bypass that for the time being?